# Change the position of a jquery ui dialog in the open event

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm having trouble changing the position of a jQuery-ui dialog box.

What I'm doing is loading an image into the dialog box within the open event.  Because of the unknown height of the image, the dialog box is no longer centred in the window.  So I also reposition it after loading the image, but the repositioning seems to be ignored.

But, if I add an alert before the repositioning, it works fine, so clearly some sort of timimg issue is in play here.

Is there any work around for this?

The relevant bit of my code is:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  open: function(e, ui){
    $("#theImage").attr("src","aRandomImage.jpg");
    alert(1);  // causes the next line to work properly
    $(this).dialog("option", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to load before repositionning:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  open: function(e, ui){
    var $img = $("#theImage"), mydialog = $(this);
    $img.bind('load',function(){ // bind load event
        mydialog.dialog("option", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
    });
    $img.attr("src","aRandomImage.jpg"); // start loading
  }
```

see : 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/

for IE8 chached images load event fixing.

Comment: Watch out for cached images. Some versions of IE won't trigger the load event on them. See: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/