# Calling function on dialog button click, while creating it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am creating a button on dialog by using options.. At that time on its click I want to call a function... I know that we can write the logic there itself, but I want to share that stuff so had separate function, but couldn't make a call to that function..code is a below

```
//here menu is dialog..
//that is scope.    
//this respective ele as this stmnt is inside the loop
menu.dialog("option", "buttons", [{ text: this.text, click: that._addClass(menu, this) }]);
```

my function is below.

```
 _addClass: function(menu, target){
      do stuff here 
    }
```

the function never hits any work around plz......

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194041/change-the-position-of-a-jquery-ui-dialog-in-the-open-event) question can help you..

Comment: thats looks like we need to define some function at the creation it self, its not possible for my case, i wanted to call the function at the time i pass option .

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
click: that._addClass(menu, this)
```

with

```
click: function() { that._addClass(menu, target); }
```

(assigning this to target beforehand)

Comment: that worked thanx, I even tried that before but it didn't work, strangely it worked now.